# How to calculate angle between two direction vectors that form a closed/open shape?

Tags: geometry, shapes, pattern-recognition

I am trying to figure out the correct trig. eq./function to determine the following:
The **Angle-change (in DEGREES) between two DIRECTION VECTORS**(already determined), that represent two line-segment.
This is used in the context of SHAPE RECOGTNITION (hand drawn by user on screen).

SO basically,

a) if the user draws a (rough) shape, such as a circle, or oval, or rectangle etc - the lines that makes up that shape are broken down in to say.. 20 points(x-y pairs).

b) I have the DirectionVector for each of these LINE SEGMENTS.

c) So the BEGINNING of a LINE SEGMENT(x0,y0), will the END points of the previous line(so as to form a closed shape like a rectangle, let's say).

SO, my question is , given the context(i.e. determinign the type of a polygon), **how does one find the angle-change between two DIRECTION VECTORS(available as two floating point values for x and y)  ???**

I have seen so many different trig. equations and I'm seeking clarity on this.

Thanks so much in advance folks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If (x1,y1) is the first direction vector and (x2,y2) is the second one, it holds:

cos( alpha ) = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / ( sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1) * sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2) )

sqrt means the square root.

Look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Especially the section "Geometric Representation".

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks a lot! I will try both of your suggestions out and if the results yield what the end-user is seeking, then THANK YOU. If not, I may be back! :) Very helpful forum- much gratitude!

Comment: One tiny more thing: Since you're new here: You can up-vote answers, and you can also select one for the "accepted" answers. This raises the "reputation" of the person who answered, so it's a nice thing to do :)

Comment: Yeah.. I've just realised that... and was gonna say "be gentle with me" as I'm not really someone who spends much time online generally and so dont' do forums that frequently as most of you do. I will give your's the up-vote for now. Once i implement the solution I will choose the "correct" answer as well. :) THANKS so much! :)

Comment: Hi, one more question Largebaer.. :0 You've assigned the result of the calculation to a cos() function. What does "alpha" mean? If i were to write C++ code, do you know how the lhs(left-hand-side would be represented)?

Comment: Would it be Cos( ( x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / ( sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1) * sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2) )... or something like that? I mean, does the result of the whole caculation on the rhs(right hand side), be fed to a Cosine function??? [scratching head here, sorry]

Comment: @Immortal:  Take the arc-cosine of both sides of the equation -- then alpha = acos( (x1*x2 + y1*y2)/bla bla bla).  Alpha will be the angle you're looking for (and will probably be in units of radians).

Comment: Wonderful ! thank you SO much Jim and everyone! Some bright Souls on this space. Nice! :) THANK YOU.

Comment: Thanks to LargeBaer(and Jim), for your accurate and useful answer and more. I have work to do in terms of other calculations that lead up to the determination of ANGLE.. but I'm nearly there and am getting reasonbly accurate outputs. CHEERS folks! Much appreciated. ~

Answer (score 3):

You could try atan2:

```
float angle = atan2(previousY-currentY, previousX-currentY);
```

but also, as the previous answers mentioned, the

angle between two verctors = acos(first.dotProduct(second))

Comment: Thanks, this seems simpler , and the previous ones arent' yielding the angle(that is visually determined by me, approx). Thanks folks. REALLY appreciate this forum and will recommend it to many.

Comment: UPDATE for all: I'm not getting the correct angle for any combination of data(lines drawn), using any of the methods above. I thought .. may be it's my DirectionVector calculation functions that are faulty, but they seem correct, given the lines I draw and the value ssupplied... So I need ot look in to this. Will keep this blog posted, until problem is solved. Thanks to all who've contributed thus far. ~IB~

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have the vector as three points (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) and (x_3, y_3).

Then you can move the points so that (x_1, y_1) == (0, 0) by

(x_1, y_1) = (x_2, y_2) - (x_1, y_1)
(x_2, y_2) = (x_3, y_3) - (x_1, y_1)

Now you have this situation:

[image]

Think of this triangle as two right-angled triangles. The first one has the angle alpha and a part of beta, the second right-angled triangle has the other part of beta.

Then you can apply:

[image]

You can calculate alpha like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may just evaluate the **dot product** between two vectors and take the appropriate **arccos** to retrieve the angle between these vectors.

Comment: THat's what I felt as well. I was tyring to get my head around the clock-wise counter-clockwise issues  tha t may come up, depending on which direction a line is drawn in, and hence .. whether i may need to consider .. whether to consider the inner angle between two lines or the outer angle(if you knwo what I mean). but the inner angle shoudl suffice for most scenarios- I think.